# What is the purpuse of PkgInfo in iOS

Tags: ios

PkgInfo store the type code and creator code and is something inherited from Mac OS Classic.

Does this file has any purpose en iOS?

Answer (score 6):

The contents of the PkgInfo file are the 4-byte package type followed by the 4-byte signature of your application.

It comes from OS X, iOS does not require this file and you don't need to do anything with it.

See the following:
Book: Programming IOS 6 By Matt Neuburg

Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/ConfigApplications.html